# The difference between company and enterprise

Tags: differences

When i go to one company, i always encounter with `Company` term(ABC company, JSC). But when i work with solutions, i always encounter with `Enterprise` term(ERP, solution for enterprise,...).

Are there anyways to separate them?

Comment: In the context, *enterprise* signifies that the solution is designed and suitable for enterprise-wide application. 'Company' has a different specific meaning in law which is not relevant to the context of solutions such as ERP. HTH.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *face* here – there's no single English term I can think of that fits all the contexts you're using it in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definition of 'Company'

An entity formed to engage in a business. A company may be organized in various ways for tax and financial liability purposes. The line of business the company is in will generally determine which business structure it chooses. There are several types of companies, including sole proprietorships, limited partnerships, limited liability partnerships, limited liability corporations, S corporations and C corporations.
Source: Investopedia

Definition of 'Enterprise'

1)a project undertaken or to be undertaken, especially one that is important or difficult or that requires boldness or energy: To keep the peace is a difficult enterprise.

2)a plan for such a project.

3)participation or engagement in such projects: Our country was formed by the enterprise of resolute men and women.

4)boldness or readiness in undertaking; adventurous spirit; ingenuity.

5)a company organized for commercial purposes; business firm.
Source : Dictionary.com

Though they can be synonyms, *enterprise* defines more the activity of a *company*. In financial analysis all ratios used to measure the economic and financial perfotrmance of a company refer to *enterprise* : like EV ( enterprise value)